# Finding average but with a maximum value per cell in excel

Tags: excel, range, max, average

I am trying to find the average of a range of cells that fall between a predefined/criteria range (i.e. 0-2) but treating the end of the range (2 - in this example) as the maximum amount to be used in calculating the average over the range of cells in excel.

Here is an example of the data I am interested finding the average for:

| COST |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 7 |

If finding the average using the range of 0-2, it should be 2, as you'd be treating anything with the cost of 2+ as 2. So, the total is 2+2+2+2=8 and there are 4 cells so the average would be 2.

Another example would find the average using the range of 0-3, the average would be 2.75, as the first value in the above table falls between the criteria range and the rest match or fall outside the high end of of range so they are assigned the maximum of 3. So, the total is 2+3+3+3=11 and there are 4 cells so the average would be 2.75.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
=SUM(IF(A2:A5>=C2,C2,A2:A5))/COUNT(A2:A5)
```

in pre-O365 it must be entered as array formula with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The above seems to have solved the issue, but I did modify it by using the SUMPRODUCT to avoid having to enter it as an array formula. Double checked my numbers and everything seems to be working as it should be.

Comment: You could also use `=AVERAGE(IF(A2:A5>3;3;A2:A5))`